# How to make php scripts run in parallel?

Tags: php, session, file-locking

script1.php

```
<?php
session_start();
sleep(10);
```

script2.php

```
<?php
session_start();
```

I run script1.php in the browser and immediately after script2.php in another browser window.
session_start() in script2.php can't execute until script1.php is not finished executing.

Why it happened and how to make php scripts run in parallel?

Comment: How is your webserver configured?

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
<?php
session_start();
session_write_close();
sleep(10);
```

Related: [Thoughts on PHP sessions](http://00f.net/2011/01/19/thoughts-on-php-sessions/)