# many images on one page some not loading

Tags: php, javascript, image, browser

I am making a Warehouse management system.

The orders come in a CSV in the morning that my script then executes.

It places a php-made barcode on the top of each order. the sample CSV i am using has around 100 unique orders on, so when i load the page that will then print orders off the server is getting 100+ requests and (im guessing) some of the images time out.

When i view source and open the link to the ones that don't work it loads the image, leading me to think i need to somehow disable the timout method on the browser.

My only other idea is to load the barcodes through javascript.

Any suggestions?

Comment: So you're loading one script that generates all of these order pages, each with their own barcodes? When the images start failing, do they keep failing or is it hit and miss?

Comment: What is max_execution_time in php.ini ?

Comment: How about you preload the images first in the browser, than show the page with the images on it? google image preloader javascript.

Comment: set ini_set("max_execution_time", "3000") on the script to make the barcode and still not loading, ill try preloading the images

Comment: Fixed this by adding a sleep function 

        function sleep_until(seconds) {
       var max_sec = new Date().getTime();
       while (new Date() < max_sec + (seconds * 1000)) {}
        return true;
        }

and sleeping every 20 images for 2/3 seconds

Comment: Is there a reason you're generating these barcodes on demand - why don't you generate each images with a script when you receive the csv directly with php (i.e. - not via a request from a webpage)

Answer (score 0):

I think what enygma may be getting at is the limited processing time php scripts have. Sometimes they get cut off after 30 seconds. Generating all of those images at one time might run over, causing your script to be killed on the server and stop sending data. Your idea of loading them in javascript is probably your best bet, as long as you only do a few at a time or do them serially.

Answer (score 0):

If you start a session in php, the session is locked and cannot be accessed by another php script until released.

Based on you generating images with php - that's quite likely the cause of what you see.

There are [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618026/how-to-make-php-scripts-run-in-parallel) which go into a bit more detail of how php and sessions work; but most likely that's the direct cause for some of your images not being received - the requests are in a single, serial queue being processed in turn because each script reads the session and doesn't release it until it's finished. The requests at the end of the queue hit a time limit one way or another and return nothing.

Therefore, ensure that you call:

```
session_write_close();
```

as soon as you can in all scripts that need access to the session to prevent them from blocking all other php requests, or better still don't use the session at all (e.g. if you're using the session for authorization just include a hash in the url and compare to that for image requests).