# Weird $_SESSION behaviour in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make php scripts run in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618026/how-to-make-php-scripts-run-in-parallel)

I'm currently having a (in my opinion) weird problem with the [`$_SESSION` superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) in PHP.

On page unload (`$(window).unload`) jQuery sends a synchronous post request to `save.php`.

It contains some data that should be saved in `$_SESSION["data"]`. I can fetch the `jqXHR` object and display some test strings contained in `responseText` with `alert()` when the current page is still shown. But on the next page those data is not available, yet. I just have to reload and everything is fine.

It seems to me that my browser (Firefox/Chrome) load the next page in background while the post request is not finished yet. Or is it a problem with `$_SESSION`?

Comment: can you please post the code?

Comment: And keep in mind that browsers are pre-fetching websites nowadays. The next page might have been already loaded *before* the user was thinking about leaving the current one.

Comment: I think that's the point. Any idea to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

May be attach event to `window.unload` is not a good idea. Browser may fetch the next page first then call the event, In that case you seesion is not change (yet). So instead of attach to unload event, You may attach to the event that cause navigation

For example:

- Attach to a link click, cancel default behavior, call your ajax save.php script then manual do navigation using `window.location.href`
- Attach to form post, cancel the post, call ajax then post form....

Hope that help